# Splitting a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I answered [Comedy about train robbery ruining the sherrif's car](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10663/identify-movie-comedy-about-train-robbery) and within seconds, I see that another user posted the same answer.

Assuming that we have the correct answer, is there a way to share the bounty given?

Comment: Are there still unclarities about the existing answers that you might want to adress in a comment?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson no, why?

Comment: Just making sure, since the question doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i am aware, no.  The asker chooses who to give the bounty to, if you're lucky enough for them to actually award the bounty.

meta.so links of interest:
[Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

[Awarding a bounty to an editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89387/awarding-a-bounty-to-an-editor)

Comment: Bounties are given automatically to the highest voted answer with 2 or more votes. If we both have 2 votes, does it split?

Comment: i thought they were granted manually.  yup, i'm the wrong person to answer this.

Comment: They are manually awarded but if it isn't manually awarded then the bounty goes away to no one unless of course, an answer given AFTER the bounty was set and it has 2 or more votes.

Comment: @dustindavis i edited in a couple of links.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the answer for manually awarding bounty is the same for automatically awarding it and in the event of a tie, it will use a timestmap. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: @DustinDavis *"I'm going to assume that the answer for manually awarding bounty is the same for automatically awarding it"* - No, it isn't. The winner of the manual bounty is chosen by the asker himself. So a common practice in your situation could be for the asker to accecpt one answer and give the bounty to another, for at least partly equal tribute.

Comment: @ChristianRau What I mean is that when automatically awarding based on criteria (at least 2 upvotes), it won't split between a tie, or in other words, there can be only one. That's a great idea for splitting the points, answer one and award bounty to the other.

Comment: @DustinDavis Ah, so with the word *"answer"* in your previous comment you didn't mean the answer selected for bounty, but the answer to your meta question. answer answer ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, sorry. I should have taken care to disambiguate my response.